# Pipeline Maven Plugin not replacing <servers> in global settings.xml from jenkins credentials

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Running: Pipeline Maven Integration Plugin 3.8.1
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin

If I create a global config file and add a `<servers>` config to it with the creds hard coded this works:
[image]

In my pipeline I use it:

```
withMaven(
    mavenSettingsConfig: 'test') {
        sh """#!/bin/bash
            mvn help:effective-settings -X
            mvn deploy
        """
    }
```

The output of `mvn help:effective-settings -X` shows my `<servers>` setting

BUT if I try to use a credential to securely store my creds this does not work:
[image]

The output of `mvn help:effective-settings -X` shows NO `<servers>` setting at all

Is this a bug with the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling bash to execute Maven:

```
withMaven(
    mavenSettingsConfig: 'test') {
        sh """#!/bin/bash
            mvn help:effective-settings -X
            mvn deploy
        """
    }
```

why not simply going:

```
withMaven(
    mavenSettingsConfig: 'test') {
        sh "mvn help:effective-settings deploy"
    }
```

and no the issue must be somewhere else cause I'm using this also for a very long time...(I would try to remove the whole comment stuff..).

Comment: changed it to your example still doesn't work. What do you mean remove comment stuff? I tried removing the entire servers block (instead of commenting out) but same issue. Not sure what the issue is. If I set my local global settings file with the same server config/creds it works

Answer (score 0):

Please follow up on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59567 where the problem was cross posted